# Window on resize - when on mobile size events not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code below :

```
     $(window).resize(function(){ 
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $("#content-services").hide();
            $("#header").unbind('click').click(function () {

                $("#content-services").slideToggle(500);

            });
        }else {
            $("#content-services").show();
            $("#header").unbind('click').click(function () {

                $("#content-services").show();
            });
        }
    });
```

When I loaded the page on desktop, and resized it manually on chrome, I got the action that I wanted.

On desktop:[image]

Manually resized on chrome: 
[image]

but when I loaded the page on small size, it showed the services section (which is fine) but the slide up action stopped working.
[image]

Can anyone check what I did wrong in my script above?

Comment: Does the script throw any errors in the JavaScript console? Have you checked the [jQuery Issues on GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues) if there are reports of your problem?

Comment: @chade_ there's no error in the console

Answer (score 0):

Your code is call only when u resizing window, so if windowd is loaded on smaller size, there is no call of resize.

Move code inside event handler to another function and call it before adding handler.

Comment: I did this but it is still not working when I loaded it on smaller screen. And there's no error in the console. https://jsfiddle.net/rt5ua411/

Comment: Can u placed html and css also?